# How to do a SQL JOIN where multiple joined rows need to contain things

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii2

When someone on my site search for an image that has multiple tags I need to query and find all images that have the searched tags, but can't seem to figure out this query.

I have an `Images` table.

The `Images` table has a relation to `Posts_Images`.

`Posts_Images` would have a relation to `Posts` table.

`Posts` has a relation to `Posts_Tags` table.

`Posts_Tags` table will have the relations to `Tags` table.

The query I have so far:

```
  SELECT "images".* FROM "images"
      INNER JOIN "posts_images" ON posts_images.image_id = images.id
      INNER JOIN "posts" ON posts.id = posts_images.post_id AND posts.state IS NULL 
      INNER JOIN "posts_tags" ON posts_tags.post_id = posts.id
      INNER JOIN "tags" ON posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id
    WHERE (("images"."order"=0) AND ("images"."has_processed"=TRUE)) AND (LOWER(tags.tag)='comic') AND ("tags"."tag" ILIKE '%Fallout%') ORDER BY "date_uploaded" DESC LIMIT 30
```

It gets no results, it is checking if the `tags` equals both values, but I want to see if any of the `tags` that were joined have all the values I need.

The desired result would be any `Post` that has a tag matching `Comic` and `ILIKE '%Fallout%'`

Comment: Did you take out the where and check to see if you had results?  I would start by verifying that and then start working on the Where clause.  Hard to help without sample data so if you are still stuck, you might flesh out your question a bit.

Comment: What happens when this condition `(("images"."order"=0) AND ("images"."has_processed" = TRUE))` is removed? How do you know zero results is not correct on that search?

Comment: The images table has an image that is order 0, which is the default image

Comment: has processed is for only the images that have been compressed/resized

Comment: apparently i need to have subquery for each tags since the query will be applied to each row at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM images JOIN
     posts_images pi
     ON pi.image_id = i.id JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.id = pi.post_id AND p.state IS NULL JOIN 
     posts_tags pt
     ON pt.post_id = p.id JOIN
     tags t
     ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE i."order" = 0 AND
      i.has_processed AND
      (LOWER(t.tag) = 'comic') OR
       (t.tag ILIKE '%Fallout%')
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) >= 2
ORDER BY date_uploaded DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

The logic is in the `HAVING` clause.  I'm not 100% sure that this is exactly what you want for multiple matches.

Comment: Awesome mate! Thanks!

Comment: The only downside in this approach is knowing how many tags you are going to need. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nbwnqV4imyczUj82Hr8Bz6/0 Here you can just count what you need.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [gordon-linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52799297/346913)’s response - query can be described using ActiveQuery:

```
Images::find()
    ->alias('i')
    ->joinWith([
        'postsImages pi',
        'postsImages.posts p',
        'postsImages.posts.tags t'
    ])
    ->where([
        'p.state' => null,
        'i.order' => 0,
        'i.has_processed' => true,
    ])
    ->andWhere(
        'or'
        'LOWER(t.tag) = "comic"',
        ['like', 't.tag', 'Fallout']
    ])
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->having('COUNT(DISTINCT tag) >= 2')
    ->orderBy('date_uploaded DESC')
    ->limit(30)
    ->all()
```

Comment: Mine is nearly identical. Ill optimize how I do my joins:

Answer (score 1):

```
   $images = Images::find()
        ->innerJoin('posts_images', 'posts_images.image_id = images.id')
        ->innerJoin('posts', 'posts.id = posts_images.post_id AND posts.state IS NULL')
        ->where(['images.order' => 0, 'images.has_processed' => true]);

    if (!is_null($query)) {
        $tags = explode(',', $query);
        $images = $images
            ->innerJoin('posts_tags', 'posts_tags.post_id = posts.id')
            ->innerJoin('tags', 'posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id');

        $tagsQuery = ['OR'];
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tag = trim(htmlentities($tag));
            if (strtolower($tag) == 'comic') {
                $tagsQuery[] = ['tags.tag' => $tag];
            } else {
                $tagsQuery[] = [
                    'ILIKE',
                    'tags.tag', $tag
                ];
            }
        }

        if (!empty($tagsQuery)) {
            $images = $images->andWhere($tagsQuery)
                ->having('COUNT(DISTINCT tags.tag) >= ' . sizeof($tags));

        }
    }
    $images = $images
        ->groupBy('images.id')
        ->orderBy(['date_uploaded' => SORT_DESC])
        ->offset($offset)
        ->limit($count);

    return $images->all();
```